# Docker Run error with ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am very new to Docker and I am able to successfully create an Image from Docker file but when I pulled it and ran a docker start on that it threw following error:

```
Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: 
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"./Myfolder\": stat ./Myfolder: no such file or directory".
```

The only place that I mentioned `/Myfolder` is in docker File `ENTRYPOINT`

as below `ENTRYPOINT ["./Myfolder"]`

While my Dockerfile looks like following:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1.1-runtime
WORKDIR /opt/outputDirectory
ENTRYPOINT ["./Myfolder"]
COPY output /opt/outputDirectory
```

and this is assuming my entry point is the ENTRYPOINT project's directory name (the one containing /bin) what could I be missing?

Comment: Please reformulate your question.

Comment: umm what part? You mean question header?

Comment: ENTRYPOINT should be a program, not a directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ENTRYPOINT specify the program that runs inside the container. You've put a directory.

See [this](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker-samples/blob/master/dotnetapp-prod/Dockerfile) example:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.0-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dotnetapp.dll"]
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it says that `dotnet` is not added to the path. Which path should it be added to? inside the image? How can I do that?

Comment: You are messing up with this line `WORKDIR /opt/outputDirectory`, that is changing the path